# Fill forms using selenium or requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to enter [this site](https://www.santandertotta.pt/pt_PT/Particulares.html) to retrieve my bank account, first I tried with selenium, but only filled username (maybe because it has 2 forms):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.santandertotta.pt/pt_PT/Particulares.html")
user = driver.find_element_by_name("usr")
user.send_keys("user")
pas = driver.find_element_by_name("claveConsultiva")
pas.send_keys("password")
login = driver.find_element_by_id("login_button").click()
```

Then, I gone rambo mode :) trying figured out why I can't fill password space, and what are the hidden values of the form using requests, this is the code:

```
url = "https://www.particulares.santandertotta.pt/pagina/indice/0,,276_1_2,00.html"     
user_agent = {"user-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/..."}
session = requests.session()
r = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")    
data = {t['name']:t.get('value') for t in soup.find_all('input', attrs={'type': 'hidden'})}
print(data)
```

But just received an empty dict. What is the best approach for enter a site with login and scrape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you access the url `https://www.santandertotta.pt/pt_PT/Particulares.html` first you have to click on the element with text as **Login** then only the the **Nome** and **Password** field appears but to access those fileds you have to switch to the frame with `id` as **ws** inducing *WebDriverWait*. Next to locate the element of **Nome** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* again as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.santandertotta.pt/pt_PT/Particulares.html")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='ttAH_button03']").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "ws")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='inputlong' and @id='identificacionUsuario']"))).send_keys("your_name")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='claveConsultiva' and @name='claveConsultiva']").send_keys("your_password")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Entrar no NetBanco Particulares").click()
```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Hey, dude, what is the point of making my answer a bit complicated? :)

Comment: thank you very much to both of you, that worked... if i want do the same with request how far off am i?

Comment: @Sátiro I am afraid, for the time being I would avoid the context of request. Feel free to ask me any question with Selenium.

Comment: hi again, how can i close the java popup in [this](https://www.eurobic.pt/) site, i use wait(driver,2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='eurobicnet-name']"))).send_keys("bah" , Keys.RETURN) a popup appear

Comment: @Sátiro Can you please raise a new question with your new requirement. So volunteers will be glad to help you out.

Comment: i would post if selenium haven't stoped work, only appear the tab name of the site and a blank page, when i figured this out i post...spend all day trying to figure out happened

Answer (score 8):

You cannot get access to Password field because it's not present on main page. To handle Password field you have to click Login button to get to Login page. Also you need to switch to iframe which contains authentication form

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.santandertotta.pt/pt_PT/Particulares.html")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Login de Particulares']").click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("ws"))
user = driver.find_element_by_name("identificacionUsuario")
user.send_keys("user")
pas = driver.find_element_by_name("claveConsultiva")
pas.send_keys("password")
pas.submit()
```